# How to create a Bootstrap sticky nav that is below a marquee but then pinned to top after scrolling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using the bootstrap v3 framework  How do I create a Navigation header that is below or part of a jumbotron or large container (like a marquee image) but sticks to the top when user scrolls down?

I started with the bootrap example and placed it below a marquee image.  However, how do you change to navbar-fixed-top and detect when user has scrolled to an appropriate position?

Example:
poolhousedigital.com

HTML:

```
<!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div id="intro" class="container">
        <h1>Navbar example</h1>
        <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
        <p>To see the difference between static and fixed top navbars, just scroll.</p>
        <p>
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/#navbar" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
        </p>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

  </div> <!-- /jumbotron -->
  <!-- Fixed navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 body {
  min-height: 2000px;
  padding-top: 0px;
    }
    .jumbotron {
    position: relative;
    background: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    min-height: 500px;
    }
    .jumbotron:after {
    content:"";
    background: url("img/2gratermay20121.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

See this example on Bootply: http://bootply.com/95797

The example uses a `masthead`, but you can replace this with your `jumbotron`.

Here is another example.. http://bootply.com/96188#

Both use the Affix plugin to attach the nav after scroll.